# Will casting and converting in Join will cause any performance impact?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working on new stored procedure and everything was set, during code review I got comment to address where it says I should not be casting/converting in joins instead asking me to convert DateTime to int date then compare those two.

**Code:**

```
INNER JOIN SchedData SD 
        ON SD.EmployeeID = CAE.EmployeeID
            AND CAST(CAST(SD.AssignDate AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate + 1
```

**Explaination :**

```
SD.AssignDate
```

is of Int date like `20100801`

```
@StartDate and @EndDate
```

are parameters of DateTime.

when I searched online in SQL Forum, they say it will not make much/any difference, that is what I have commented back in review, but I just want to re-confirm from the guys who are well known in SQL, I am using MS Sql.

here is the link which says about cast in Sql Forum

[SQL](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/643b6eda-fa03-4ad3-85a1-051f02097c7f/how-much-do-cast-statements-affect-performance?forum=transactsql)

Please let me know which is feasible to work w.r.t performance.

If there is a better way, I would be glad to implement that code.

Comment: When you cast a field it usually makes it non-sargable. (look it up). When it's non sargable it can't use an index on the column `SD.AssignDate`. If you instead do the convert on the parameters, you aren't doing a convert on the field and it becomes sargable and therefore able to utilise an index.

Comment: That link is just about casting in the select. It's not about casting on join or predicate columns which is what you're doing here.

Comment: Cast(somefield as date) is sargable,you have to use right data type

Comment: @Nick, What you saying is making some sense, would you explain or the part of code which will explain and what exactly mean "Convert on the Parameters"

Comment: I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cast a field it usually makes it non-sargable. (look it up). When it's non-sargable it can't make use of an index on the column `AssignDate` (although I've heard it's getting better at it in later versions of SQL). If you instead do the convert on the parameters, then you aren't doing a convert on the field and it becomes sargable and therefore able to utilise an index.

The link you posted is about casting in the select. It's not about casting on *join* or *predicate* columns which is what you're doing here.

For example change your code to this:

```
AND SD.AssignDate BETWEEN 
CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),@StartDate,112)) 
AND
CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),@EndDate,112))
```

Now you don't have a function around a field, and it can utilise a index on that column if it exists.... or if one exists in future

I suggest you use CTRL-L to observe whats happening and compare queries.

Here's some interesting background reading, basically saying that *some* functions around columns are OK.

http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server/

Comment: Sorry for replying late, I was implementing few more changes, anyways I agree with you and I have currently declared variables at top and used those in inner joins, However there is not much changes in execution plan,  after doing this, but I still go with you on your suggestion.

Comment: There'd need to be a useful index on, or including, the field `AssignDate` for there to be a difference. Even if there isn't one now, you want to be able to add one in future without having to change any code to make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

from your own link :

> As a general rule, doing CASTs or CONVERTs on items in your SELECT
>   clause cost almost nothing.  (Note that **CASTs or CONVERTs in WHERE
>   or ON clauses can be very expensive** since they will keep SQL Server
>   from making effective use of indexes).

Best way is to convert the Datatype of that column into a proper Date or Datetime if the no.of rows is reasonably small.

Comment: Making schema changes might be a little complicated. Better off just casting the parameter to match the column

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand and guess

```
AND CAST(CAST(SD.AssignDate AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate + 1
```

should be part of where clause and not inner join.

Also if

```
SD.AssignDate
```

is already a date time field then there is not point converting it to varchar then converting it to date time.

Comment: With an inner join it technically doesn't matter

Comment: Using Cast/Convert in where clause is very expensive! I have come across this

Comment: Agreed. He should convert his parameters to the same type as SD.AssignedDate and do the join/filtering.